# Sails.js destroy instance with one-to-one associations

Tags: orm, sails.js

I am working on a model with a couple of attributes that are one-to-one and one-way associations. When I destroy an instance of that main model, will it also destroy the associated instances?

And if not, what would be a convenient way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment Waterline does not support cascade deletion of records.
A relatively clean way of doing this right now would be to add an `afterDestroy` hook to your model.

```
// Pet.js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    owner: {
      model: 'person'
    }
  }
}

// Person.js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    pet: {
      model: 'pet'
    }
  },

  afterDestroy: function(deletedRecords, next) {
    async.each(deletedRecords, function(person, cb) {
        Pet.destroy({owner: person.pet}, cb);
      }
    ], next);
  }
}
```

The `afterDestroy` function will run every time `Person` records are deleted. If you want people to be deleted when pets are deleted as well, you need to do the same thing in the `Pet` model.